# Meteor: Reuse existing browser tab with each (Android) NFC tap?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, meteor, nfc

I'm developing a Meteor web app that loads upon tapping an NFC tag (Android). I'm finding that (of course) tapping the same NFC tag (with the same embedded URL) opens a new window or tab in the browser. The problem is three-fold: 1) it clutters the browser with multiple tabs referencing the same web app thus confusing the user, 2) grows browser memory, and 3) forces Meteor to perform a complete (and slow) download for the new tab rather than reusing the same web app already loaded. The appcache package does not seem to make a difference in this  case. This delays the page from appearing quickly after a tap because of the app reload.

Is there any (clever) way around this? I would hope to reuse an existing tab with the same hostname/domain to avoid all of the issues above. I don't know enough yet about HTML5 Javascript API that might offer some kind of solution. I'm afraid this might not be possible. I was thinking, if it were possible, I could load a small app first that inspects the browser environment, redirecting to the full Meteor app, or finding an existing window/tab with same hostname and fetching a new url within that window (with the updated tag ID for instance).

Someone might suggest using Meteor native mobile app, but this has several other problems of its own, including the fact the app must be installed via Play store which is friction vs. web app that just loads without installing an app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd drop meteor out of this question..... I'd say the decision of whether to open a new browser tab is to do with whatever reads the NFC tag and opens the URL, and there's probably nothing browser code can do to change that.

Comment: @KeithNicholas agreed, but wanted to give additional info in case someone might know of a way to do this conveniently with Meteor, but likely not.

Comment: Did you find a reasonable solution for your problem? We are facing the exact same dilemma with an NFC driven Identification for our machines. The customer should directly go to the device's settings page (in our web application) to view the status or make ajustments.